# Handling Missing ID field for prisma and data from API call

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, model, prisma

I fetch data from an api like this:

```
async function getApiData() {
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < PAGE_COUNT; i++) {
    const apiData = fetch(...);
  }
  const apiData = await Promise.all(promises);
  return apiData;
}
```

This function returns a promise which resolves to an array containing objects, say each object (representing data from an API call) matches a pattern like this:

`const exampleData = { name: 'john', lastName: 'doe' };`

I can create a typing for this in Typescript, and specify that typing for my `getApiData` function.

I'm also using prisma, and have a schema like this:

```
model Person {
  id  Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  lastName String
}
```

This means I can get a specific typing from prisma by importing it:

`import { Person } from '@/prisma/client'`

However, that typing is slightly different from the typing I might use inside my `getApiData` function, because I am missing the `id` field there. If I try to import my prisma typing and use it inside `getApiData`, I get an error:

```
Property 'id' is missing in type  but required in type `{name, lastName} but required in type 'Repository'
```

This raises two questions for me:

1. How can I re-use the prisma typing for my shaped API data? It would feel wrong to make a separate interface that only has a one field difference, that seems clunky.
2. How do I insert *any* data inside my prisma database, from a typescript perspective? If I put data into my database, it always will not have the `id` field as that's created once I insert the row, so how can I use any typings for this? And does Prisma expect a certain typing for when I insert data, or can I just insert anything?

Comment: You can import the `%name%CreateInput` or `%name%UncheckedCreateInput` variants from the prisma client. `import { PersonCreateInput } from '@/prisma/client'`

Comment: thanks feel free to leave an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the typescript utility types [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) or [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) for this type of issue.

```js
import { Person } from '@prisma/client'

async function getApiData(): PartialPersonData[] | undefined {
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < PAGE_COUNT; i++) {
    const apiData = fetch(...);
  }
  const apiData = await Promise.all(promises);
  return apiData;
}

// either of these could work it depends on your goals/needs
type PartialPersonData = Partial<Person> // partial === any of Person fields are valid
type OmitIdPersonData = Omit<Person, 'id'> // omit === all Person fields as is omitting id
```